# How to write the second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2(TM)$ as an explicit cochain?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

The second Stiefel-Whitney class $$w_2(TM) \in H^2 (M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$$
measures the obstruction to finding a 3-frame over the 2-skeleton. If $w_1$ was trivial,
the manifold being oriented, $T$M can already be trivialized over the 1-skeleton.
And we picked an orientation of $M$, then by using this orientation we can complete any 3-frame to a 4-frame. Therefore we can say that, for oriented manifolds, $w_2(TM)$ is the obstruction to trivializing $TM$ over the 2-skeleton31 of $M$.

This is what described in Alexandru Scorpan: The Wild World of 4 Manifold p.162:

[image]

> **Question: so how do we write the second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2(TM)$ as a cochain field explicitly (please be as explicit as possible for your construction)?**

Comment: What is a cochain field?

Comment: In my case, I hope, writing down a local function that can assign to a 2-simplex of a simplicial complex of $d$-dimensional manifold. You can remove the "field" and simply I meant cochain.

Comment: Continue: In terms of 2-cocycle, you need to satisfy the cocycle condition.  In fact, we have to ask the $w_2$ as 2-cochain satisfies the cocycle condition because they are characteristic class (so cohomology class in this sense).

Comment: Try googling “combinatorial formula for Stiefel-Whitney classes.”

Comment: thanks + 1 , any particular ref you suggest?

Comment: I have not looked at them in 40+ years. I believe Jeff Cheeger wrote a paper. Start there?

Comment: thanks Jeff Cheeger I am looking for